# vbscript to prompt message on a file execution

Tags: vbscript

I am looking for a VBscript code that will prompt a message box whenever a user opens any application/ a particular application. And, the vbscript should always be running.
I am new to coding. Please help!!

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set objEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace")

Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = objEvents.NextEvent
    msgbox objReceivedEvent.ProcessName
    If lcase(objReceivedEvent.ProcessName) = lcase("Notepad.exe") then 
        Msgbox "Process exited with exit code " & objReceivedEvent.ExitStatus
        WshShell.Run "c:\Windows\notepad.exe", 1, false
    End If
Loop
```

This will get you started. This monitors process's exits. Change `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` to `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` to do process starts.